# Spring boot + Spring data elastic search + elastic search 5.6.0

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data

I am trying to build a Spring Boot App(1.5.9.RELEASE) with Elastic Search 5.4.1 and I have this conflict when I run maven > install

[image: failed to run]

My pom.xml is

```
<properties>
    ...
    <elasticsearch.version>5.4.1</elasticsearch.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RC2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
    </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help will be welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the compatibility issues between spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch and springboot.
Have a look at this and change accordingly

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Spring-Data-Elasticsearch---Spring-Boot---version-matrix

Comment: Thanks I’ll take a look